# Toolbar with "Previous" and "Next" for Keyboard inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol, accessory

I've been trying to implement this toolbar, where only the 'Next' button is enabled when the top textField is the firstResponder and only the 'Previous' button is enabled when the bottom textField is the firstResponder.

It kind of works, but what keeps happening is I need to tap the 'Previous'/'Next' buttons twice each time to enable/disable the opposing button.

Am I missing something in the responder chain that's making this happen?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
}


- (UIToolbar *)keyboardToolBar {

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Previous", @"Next"]];
    [segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    segControl.momentary = YES;
    segControl.highlighted = YES;

    [segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeRow:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
    [segControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];

    UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segControl];

    NSArray *itemsArray = @[nextButton];

    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray];

    return toolbar;
}

- (void)changeRow:(id)sender {

    int idx = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (idx == 1) {
        [sender setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        [sender setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        self.topText.text = @"Top one";
        [self.bottomText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [sender setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        [sender setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        self.bottomText.text =@"Bottom one";
        [self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (!textField.inputAccessoryView) {
        textField.inputAccessoryView = [self keyboardToolBar];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a segmented control instead of two buttons?

Comment: A `UISegmentedControl` is definitely more eye candy than two buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, after looking at the brilliant [BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls), I tried implementing the enabling and disabling of the segmented control in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, instead of where my `@selector` was. I also introduced a variable for the segmented control.
It works now.
Here's the amended code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (UIToolbar *)keyboardToolBar {

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    self.segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Previous", @"Next"]];
    [self.segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    self.segControl.momentary = YES;

    [self.segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeRow:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
    [self.segControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];

    UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.segControl];

    NSArray *itemsArray = @[nextButton];

    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray];

    return toolbar;
}

- (void)changeRow:(id)sender {

    int idx = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

    if (idx) {
        self.topText.text = @"Top one";
        [self.bottomText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        self.bottomText.text =@"Bottom one";
        [self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (!textField.inputAccessoryView) {

        textField.inputAccessoryView = [self keyboardToolBar];
    }
    if (textField.tag) {

        [self.segControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        [self.segControl setEnabled:YES forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Here is a `UIViewController` extension that I use whenever I need a group of `UITextField`s to provide navigation via input accessory. No need to use `UITextField` delegation with this approach, and adding the behavior to multiple forms becomes a single-liner. Also supports the 'Done' button to dismiss.

```
extension UIViewController {
  func addInputAccessoryForTextFields(textFields: [UITextField], dismissable: Bool = true, previousNextable: Bool = false) {
    for (index, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
      let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
      toolbar.sizeToFit()

      var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
      if previousNextable {
        let previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Backward Arrow"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        previousButton.width = 30
        if textField == textFields.first {
          previousButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
          previousButton.target = textFields[index - 1]
          previousButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
        }

        let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Forward Arrow"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        nextButton.width = 30
        if textField == textFields.last {
          nextButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
          nextButton.target = textFields[index + 1]
          nextButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
        }
        items.append(contentsOf: [previousButton, nextButton])
      }

      let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
      let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
      items.append(contentsOf: [spacer, doneButton])


      toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
      textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
  }
}
```

example:

```
let field1 = UITextField()
let field2 = UITextField()
addInputAccessoryForTextFields([field1, field2], dismissable: true, previousNextable: true)
```

Here's a reasonable [arrow icon](https://icons8.com/icons/3299/next).

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Dude, you're a genius! Much simpler than other examples that I found online... thanks a bunch! ☺️

Comment: best solution so far

Comment: Great solution!. Can you please provide how to access previous, next and done buttons action in other classes (like delegates)

Comment: Probably using this. Few issues: dismissable does not do anything and the arrow icon is 404.

Answer (score 17):

Swift:

```
lazy var inputToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    var toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.translucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .bordered, target: self, action: "inputToolbarDonePressed")
    var flexibleSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var fixedSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    var nextButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "keyboardPreviousButton"), style: .bordered, target: self, action: "keyboardNextButton")
    nextButton.width = 50.0
    var previousButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "keyboardNextButton"), style: .Bordered, target: self, action: "keyboardPreviousButton")

    toolbar.setItems([fixedSpaceButton, nextButton, fixedSpaceButton, previousButton, flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolbar
    }()
```

In UITextFieldDelegate

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar

    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion here is "don't reinvent the wheel".

Having `Prev` and `Next` button over a keyboard for switching between `UITextView`s is so common that you can find many good implementations ready to use.

Check out [BSKeyboardControl](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls), for instance.

Comment: Thanks for that, Gabriele. I thought I'd be able to do it simply using these few methods instead of importing an (admittedly small) implementation. Still can't see what I've done wrong though, and it's annoying me. If nobody turns up with a correction (or I suss it out looking at BSKeyboardControl), I'll mark you as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

Updated for **Swift 3.0**

```
lazy var inputToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    var toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = .default
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ContactViewController.inputToolbarDonePressed))
    var flexibleSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var fixedSpaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    var nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ContactViewController.keyboardNextButton))
    var previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Previous", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ContactViewController.keyboardPreviousButton))

    toolbar.setItems([fixedSpaceButton, previousButton, fixedSpaceButton, nextButton, flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolbar
}()
```

And then:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = inputToolbar
    return true
}
```

Remember to change thange "ContactViewController" to the name of your View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the pod [UITextField-Navigation](https://github.com/T-Pham/UITextField-Navigation):

`pod 'UITextField-Navigation'`

It adds two lazy-loaded properties `nextTextField` and `previousTextField` to any UITextField. All you need is to specify the `nextTextField` either on the interface builder or programmatically, and the toolbar is added to the keyboard for you.

Programmatically:

```
import UITextField_Navigation

let textField1 = UITextField()
let textField2 = UITextField()
textField1.nextTextField = textField2

assert(textField2 == textField1.nextTextField)
assert(textField1 == textField2.previousTextField)
```

On the Interface Builder:

[image: connect nextTextField in Interface Builder]
[image]

Comment: Hi, How to customize toolbar

Comment: @Nikhil Pandey: please check out the readme https://github.com/T-Pham/UITextField-Navigation/blob/master/README.md#ui-customization

Comment: Hi I believe you have updated the library but not the documentation page on GitHub and the example project.

Comment: Hi I checked the library, the documentation appears old , e.g., if i use the function : -func navigationFieldDidTapDoneButton(_ navigationField: NavigationField) {
        navigationField.resignFirstResponder(). it says there is nothing like Navigation Field.  The current syntax I believe is   - func textFieldNavigationDidTapDoneButton(_ textField: UITextField).

Comment: Yours is an awesome library, please update the GitHub page and may I request you to make fresh documentation and update example project again.

Comment: @NikhilPandey: it appears that you are using version 2 of the library. Please update to version 3. The one with `navigationField` is version 3.
In case you wish to keep using version 2, here is the documentation for version 2: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/UITextField-Navigation/2.0.0/

Comment: Yeah just got my pod file updated. Many thanks and best wishes to you. Keep it up:).

Comment: Hi Pham,While using the latest version I am getting following in my Xcode debugger, can you look into this as I believe there is a print statement in your file navigationFieldDidTapNextButton: <UITextField: 0x7ffa0b42ebd0; frame = (0 0; 200 30); text = '200'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000454d00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000004214c0>>

Comment: Ah, you must be using the example app. The print statement there is to demonstrate how to handle the previous, next and done buttons yourself with your app.

Comment: @ Pham : No, I am getting this message while I am using the framework in my Xcode project and not the example app.

Comment: That's strange since I don't leave any print in my lib source.

Comment: That's why asking you to check, there may be one left .

Comment: Strange, still getting those messages.

Comment: Whenever two text fields are connected via nextNavigationField following types of log messages occur

Reading from private effective user settings.
navigationFieldDidTapNextButton: <UITextField: 0x7fb48d725cb0; frame = (0 0; 328 30); text = '100'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800045aa90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000035a20>>
 
Though no problem with running of app is found but why this log message appears should be investigated.

Comment: @ThanhPham You've got an awesome little library there. I used it with my Swift 3 project and faced no issues at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (UIToolbar *)keyboardToolBar {

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[toolbar sizeToFit];

UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]       initWithItems:@[@"Previous", @"Next"]];
[segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
segControl.momentary = YES;
segControl.highlighted = YES;

[segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeRow:)  forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
[segControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segControl];

NSArray *itemsArray = @[nextButton];

[toolbar setItems:itemsArray];

int idx = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

if (idx == 1) {
    [sender setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
else {
    [sender setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
}

return toolbar;
}

- (void)changeRow:(id)sender {


int idx = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

if (idx == 1) {
    self.topText.text = @"Top one";
    [self.bottomText becomeFirstResponder];
}
else {
    self.bottomText.text =@"Bottom one";
    [self.topText becomeFirstResponder];
}
}


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (!textField.inputAccessoryView) {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = [self keyboardToolBar];
}
}
```

you dont need to enable other item as they reinitialise every time when keyboard changes ....

Comment: Where do you get sender on `keyboardToolBar:`? Its `setSegmentedControlStyle` also was deprecated. Any solution?