# How to enable the next or previous button of keyboard in swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard, iphone-keypad

I want to enable the next button of keyboard programmatically, when my next object is of UITableview

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolbar with "Previous" and "Next" for Keyboard inputAccessoryView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148276/toolbar-with-previous-and-next-for-keyboard-inputaccessoryview)

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and set the return key.

or you can set by

```
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
```